# Meaning of "I won't be long"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

> I won't be long.

What does this phrase mean, and when would it be used?

I heard this phrase in the song "Cheap Thrills."

Comment: You should add enough of the lyrics to establish the context. In general, it means "I won't be (gone/away) long".

Comment: It can mean "I won't take too much time (to do something)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lyrics are as follows:

> Come on, come on, turn the radio on 
>   It's Friday night and I won't be long
>   Gotta do my hair, I put my make up on
>   It's Friday night and I won't be long
>
> Til I hit the dance floor
>   Hit the dance floor
>   I got all I need
>   No I ain't got cash
>   I ain't got cash
>   But I got you baby

In this context "I won't be long" means that Sia won't take take too much time to do her makeup and get ready. She wants to dance with her partner sooner rather than later.